# Good practice to instantiate classes from an enum value

Tags: java, enums, instantiation

I've been searching to many places but I didn't find a good answer for my problem:

I have an enum, for example:

```
public enum Window { CLASSIC, MODERN }
```

and I need to separate the behavior of my application according to the enum value, like that:

```
switch (myWindow.getType()) {
  case CLASSIC: new ClassicWindow(...);
  case MODERN: new ModernWindow(...);
}
```

I know what you think: simply put that in the enum and basta, however this is not the only class depending on my enum! And I can't write as many object creation methods as I have objects!

Simply put, what can I do in this situation? A friend of mine said to me to get rid of the enum and to use derived classes everytime, but in the end I'd have to create as many instances as subclasses for all my tests!

In short, I'm stuck.

Do you know a best practice for that? Thanks

Comment: [Abstract Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), rather than good practices for using enums. The code you're intending to write will be full of switch statements, with one condition for each possible value of the enum - making it hard to maintain and extend in the long run. A better idea would be to refactor each possible case's behavior in a separate class, maybe using the [Abstract Factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Actually the Abstract Factory pattern can be what I'd be looking for... In the abstract i'd have a factory method for each of the elements: one for the window, one for the skin...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel dumb for not having thought of that :/

Answer (score 0):

This is the factory pattern.  [This example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#Java_3) actually shows exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I know the Factory method pattern, the thing is that I'd need a factory in every place I need to parse the enum.

For instance, I have a class Window which I build a subclass according to the enum, but I also have a class Skin, Button, etc... and in each and every one of them I use the factory to build the subclass. If I add another enum, I'd have to parse all those factories to add the new subclasses, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You could either implement an interface in your enum and have them act as a factory:

```
interface WindowBuilder {
    Window makeWindow();
}

enum WindowType implements WindowBuilder {
    SIMPLE {
        public Window makeWindow() { return new SimpleWindow() }
    },
    [... other enums]
}
```

or you could use reflection and bind a class to the enum type to have them (again) work as a factory:

```
enum WindowType {
    SIMPLE(SimpleWindow.class),
    [... other enums]

    private final Class<? extends Window> wndType;

    private WindowType(Class<? extends Window> wndType) {
        this.wndType = wndType;
    }

    public Window makeWindow() {
        // in fact you will need to either catch the exceptions newInstance can throw, or declare the method can throw them
        return this.wndType.newInstance();
    }
}
```

Either way you will be able to call them like that afterward:

```
Window window = myWindow.getType().makeWindow();
```

Comment: I thought of that too but It's too narrow since a lot of elements are using this enum. I can't do something like "SIMPLE(SimpleWindow.class, SimpleButton.class, SimpleSkin.class) and so on.